# easy way to profile method timings in .net

Tags: .net, profiler

could someone help me to find out how to get the time of execution time of c# methods
when i run the application.

if i use clr profiler , i can get object allocation details.

but i am looking for methods or lines of code which took long time to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Try JetBrain's [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) or [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/ants_profiler/index.htm) profiler.

Screenshot of dotTrace profiler's output:

[image]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/features/screenshots/20/cpuSnapshot.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you get hold of a commercial profiler if you can. They provide much better  laid out information to help you isolate where the bottlenecks and memory leaks may be. Check out Red Gate [ANTS profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/ants_profiler/index.htm) or JetBrains [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/). I wrote a small article walking you through how to use one [here](http://thinkersroom.com/bytes/2007/10/01/profiling-net-applications-i/)